# Bad position of bottom background in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

When I switch to responsive mode, bottom white image is not at the bottom of parent `ul` element.

Can you please help me with this? Image has `position:absolute` with 0 (marked with red rectangle on provided screenshot) from bottom of parent element so it should be working without problem....

Here is link to page where you can inspect elements: [Slider](http://michalurban.cz/problem/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probleme reside in the fixed height in the  background pseudo element :

so try to set height dynamicly using calc [css3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) and set `background-size` to `100%` :

```
.slideshow:after {
    content: "";
    background: url(../img/bottom.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(31%);
    z-index: 999999;
}
```